# How do I know the data is empty on Trustpilot Embeded?

Tags: javascript, trustpilot

I'm following this [instruction](https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/203840826-Add-a-TrustBox-to-a-webpage) to embed the Trustpilot on my website. It will render a  tag that contains the data.
I would like to check when the data is empty like this:

[image]

I found that the Trustpilot will create an object like this window.Trustpilot.Modules.WidgetManagement but still don't know how to detect that the data is empty or not.

Comment: Is the "No reviews for this product yet" part text, or an image? If it's text then checking the injected elements contents should be a relatively easy option.

Comment: The "No reviews for this product yet" part is rendered inside a <iframe> tag and this tag doesn't allow me to interact with it.